# Temporarily stop all scheduled jobs in Jenkins from running

Tags: jenkins

I'm in the process of migrating Jenkins from one server to another. I've no issues with the migration process.

But sooner I start my new server the scheduled jobs start executing, which is proving to be dangerous. I need to make sure that everything is in place before activating the new server.

Is there any way to deter any of the jobs from executing while the new server is active?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a post-initialization script that puts Jenkins into quiet mode right after startup.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post-initialization+script

Answer (score 3):

execute an '/script':

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.class).each {i -> i.setDisabled(true); i.save() }
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.AbstractProject.class).each {i -> i.setDisabled(true); i.save() }
```

Not my idea, from [jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Disable+all+jobs)

Answer (score 1):

Try using https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Exclusive+Execution+Plugin. You can keep jenkins in shutdown or Quiet mode for some time till your new instance is ready to function.

Answer (score 0):

### Use the Jenkins CLI

To prevent any jobs from being run, use quiet-down:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:9090 -auth user:token quiet-down
```

To re-enable job scheduling:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:9090 -auth user:token cancel-quiet-down
```

Scheduled jobs will be added to the queue during the quiet-down time, and will be run after canceling the quiet-down. If that's not what you want, you may use `clear-queue` before canceling the quiet-down.

There is a little downside: in the GUI, Jenkins will announce that it is preparing for shutdown, which wouldn't be true in this case. I find that acceptable, because we use it during backup at night when no one will read the announcement anyway. However, another option would be to take nodes offline, then online again using `offline-node` and `online-node`.

---

### Quick Setup

Only if you haven't set up Jenkins CLI already:

- You can obtain the Jenkins CLI from your Jenkins server by downloading it from <your_jenkins_url>/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
- Instead of using your actual password to authenticate, obtain a token from <your_jenkins_url>/me/configure
- For more details, refer to the [Jenkins Handbook: Jenkins CLI](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/)

Answer (score 0):

Referencie: https://xanderx.com/post/cancel-all-queued-jenkins-jobs/

Run this in Manage Jenkins > Script Console:

`Jenkins.instance.queue.clear()`